# azure bizspark - notification if balance below the threshold value

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

we are using azure BizSpark subscription. we are allowed 150USD for free for one month. The issue we are facing once we used 150 and credit become 0 the VM automatically disable and we have to recharge and start VM again. I want alert on credit threshold value i-e if balance < 10 then a notification email will be send to me.

Please some one suggest can i configure this kind of alert notification via azure portal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it on [Azure account manage Portal](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions).

[image]
More information about this please refer to this link:[Set up billing or credit alerts for your Microsoft Azure subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-set-up-alerts)

You should ensure `Billing Alert Service` is active.[image]

Note: You should be  Account Admin for your Azure subscription.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Now when i am "Billing Alert Service" page under "
preview features" tab. once i clicked try now button a popup open i click ok button then it shows same page again and again with "sign up again" button. now error message shown. do not know whats going on. any idea? i have admin account.

Comment: @MuhammadHabib  You should ensure `Billing Alert Service` is active. Then you could see the alter.

Comment: Follow this.  ` [the Subscriptions page](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions)`--`Click a subscription to view details and usage.`--`Your subscription`-->`Alter`