# Monitoring Azure Subscription limits

Tags: azure

I would like to receive an email if I approach limits on a resource in Azure. Is there a way to sign up for notifications of this kind?

I considered using Azure alerts. It seems you can trigger alerts from metrics or azure logs, but I couldn't figure out how to trigger action on anything related to resource limits.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You could do it on [Azure account manage Portal](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions). When you reach the limit, you will receive e-mail.

Please refer to this link:[Set up billing or credit alerts for your Microsoft Azure subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-set-up-alerts)

You should ensure `Billing Alert Service` is active.[image]

Note: You should be  Account Admin for your Azure subscription.

You could check the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879300/azure-bizspark-notification-if-balance-below-the-threshold-value).

Answer (score 0):

No readymade Alerts on resource quotas.

Brilliant article by Tom will help you to configure such tailored alerts, using OMS Log analytics.
[Get Alerts as you approach your Azure resource quotas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2017/06/11/get-alerts-as-you-approach-your-azure-resource-quotas/)

> Azure PowerShell includes the cmdlets Get-AzureRmVMUsage and Get-AzureRmStorageUsage which will report your current usage and quotas for a range of different resource types

Also You can utilize Azure billing alert service:
[Set up billing or credit alerts for your Microsoft Azure subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-set-up-alerts)